# Angularjs routing: Get 404 upon browser refresh

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am using Angular JS, asp.net web api project.

When I route using the following url

http://localhost:3458/Profile

I get the following error

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for...

But when I use the following link

http://localhost:3458/#/Profile

I do not get the 404 error.

I have googled and looked at other Stack overflow answers to the same question but still no success. Here is my code.

```
appointmentReminderApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    $routeProvider
        // Auth 
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl: "App/Home.html",
            controller: "HomeController"
        })
        .when("/Register", {
            templateUrl: "App/AuthForm/templates/register.html",
            controller: "authRegisterController"
        })
    .when("/Profile", {
        templateUrl: "App/ProfileForm/templates/profile.html",
        controller: "profileController"
    })
        // All else
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" });
});
```

Comment: to use html5 mode, you have to enable rewriting on your server as well as within the angular app.  check here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: I think the problem here is that the .nets MVC Routing it taking precedence

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your server to send any request for  `http://localhost:3458/Profile` and any other URL you will be routing, to your actual angular app's page `index.html` or whatever your page is.